# Get User SID of remote computer

Tags: powershell

I'm learning and can't figure out how to get the below code to work on a remote computer.

I want to retrieve the SID of a particular user on a remote computer

The below snippet works to retrieve the SID of the logged in user on the local computer.  I am searching for a way to use this to find a specific SID for a remote system.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$currentusersid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username |
ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value }
```

Comment: If you want to stick with your approach then follow Martin's solution, that will give you for the remote computers provided PSRemoting should be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you:

```
[wmi] "win32_userAccount.Domain='domainname',Name='username'"
```

Remotely:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "name = 'username' AND domain = 'domainname'" -Credential $cred
```

Oldschool method:

```
wmic useraccount where (name='username' and domain='domainname') get name,sid
```

Comment: this will return the SID of the AD computer, not of the user logged on to that computer (which is wat the questioner asks).

Comment: Yes. I overlooked the question

Comment: Thank you both.  Exactly what i was needing.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`Invoke-Command`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135225) cmdlet which takes a `-Computername` parameter.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'whatever' -ScriptBlock {
    $currentusersid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username |
    ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value }
}
```